# Spring Boot: Wrong content-type when using @GetMapping{produces:...} with multiple MediaType to serve image

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web

I'm trying to return BufferedImage in a controller like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/image")
public class ImageController {
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @GetMapping(value = "/thumb/{bookId}",produces = {MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, MediaType.IMAGE_GIF_VALUE, MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE})
    public BufferedImage getThumb(@PathVariable("bookId") long bookId) throws IOException {
        String path = this.imageMapper.findThumbPathById(bookId);
        return ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(new File(path)));
    }
}
```

and I've registered a HttpMessageConverter:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebMVCConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

It worked alright serving .jpg image, but when serving .png or .gif files, I got the error below:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Bogus input colorspace
    at java.desktop/com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeImage(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.desktop/com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeOnThread(JPEGImageWriter.java:1007) ~[na:na]
    at java.desktop/com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.write(JPEGImageWriter.java:371) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter.java:259) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
```

Then I found in response headers that the Content-Type is still "image/jpeg" but not png or gif.
What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to set the "Accept" request header to the specific type you want. I'd guess that otherwise Spring is just using the first one in your `produces` list. (Which you can test by reordering it.)